# Layered navigation system php

Tags: php, navigation, layered

I'm stuck trying to create a basic navigation system for a site.

I've got a .txt file that I'm trying to put the whole site nav into then I'm looping through line by line and creating nested s. This works fine, but I have two problems:

1-I have a separate navigation  in a different div so it's not nested and I don't know how to populate that  since it doesn't happen in the first loop.

2-I don't know how to change the class of the parent nav link without using JQuery or manually adding a $parent variable to each page.

Here is my code:

nav.txt

```
index.php:Home
products.php:Products:2
    ace.php:Ace Blade
    electrodes.php:Electrodes
    megasoft.php:Mega Soft
    lletz.php:Lletz Loops
    megapower.php:Mega Power:-2
samples.php:Samples
gogreen.php:Go Green:2
    wastecalculator.php:Waste Calculator
    environmental.php:Environmental Considerations:-2
about.php:About Us
```

MY NAV FUNCTION:

```
<?php 

function  main_navigation()
{    

$active_page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

?>

<div class="main_nav">
    <ul>

        <?php
            $nav = fopen("template/nav.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
            //Output a line of the file until the end is reached        
            while(!feof($nav)){ 
                $line = fgets($nav);
                list($url, $name, $layer) = explode(":", $line);

                echo "<li>";
                if ($active_page == $url) {
                        echo "<div class='active'>".$name."</div>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<a href='".$url."'>".$name."</a>";
                    };
                if ($layer == 2){
                    echo "<ul>";
                }elseif($layer == -2){
                    echo "</ul>";
                }else{
                    echo "</li>";
                };

            };
            fclose($nav);
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?
};

?>
```

So, again it's not shown here, but I'm trying to add a third "layer" but it isn't nested within this .

Comment: Why this way? If you are using a text file I guess its not realy dynamic and then its better to just write the HTML code and put that in an include file. That is faster and easier to debug. If its only for the $active_page part then there are better ways than this.

Comment: Point me in the direction of the better way?

Comment: Reason for the .txt file was just to make maintenance easier and have the navigation accessible outside of a mess of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the navigation outside a mess of code you could use something like the following. This would allow for layering but still simple codeing. And I think a lot easier to understand when you check this code back in a year or so then using `-2` and `2`

```
menu.php

<?php
function AddMenuItem($url, $name)
{
  $active_page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

  if ($active_page == $url)
    echo "<div class='active'>".$name."</div>";
  else
    echo "<a href='".$url."'>".$name."</a>";
}
?>

<ul>
  <li>
    <?php echo AddMenuItem("index.php", "Home"); ?>
  </li>
  <li>
    <?php echo AddMenuItem("products.php", "Products"); ?>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <?php echo AddMenuItem("ace.php", "Ace Blade"); ?>
      </li>
      <li>
        <?php echo AddMenuItem("electrodes.php", "Electrodes"); ?>
      </li>
      <li>
        <?php echo AddMenuItem("megasoft.php", "Mega Soft"); ?>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <?php echo AddMenuItem("samples.php", "Samples"); ?>
  </li>
</ul>



index.php, products.php, ace.php, etc.

<?php require_once("menu.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Guess I was over thinking it.